# Add two input values as string in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, string-concatenation

I´m trying to add two input values as string not as number, the problem is that they are actually numbers.

```
'clabe' => $this->input->post('clabe2') + $this->input->post('dc')
```

Where clabe2 = 123 and dc = 4;

I want to get result as  1234  not 127

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Learn that concatenation of strings is done with `.`

Comment: Use  concatenation operator http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do something like this**

*Use concatenation operator `.` for string concatenation*

```
'clabe' => $this->input->post('clabe2') . $this->input->post('dc');
```

For more : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: I feel like a dumb right now, anyways thanks a lot bro!

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate this and assign to variable
like this:

```
$var = $this->input->post('clabe2') . $this->input->post('dc');
'clabe' => $var
```

Comment: I feel like a dumb right now, anyways thanks a lot bro!